# Pattern library for addressable LED strips

Tags: led

Is there any central place that we can get drawing pattern functions for the addressable LED strips like the once based on the WS2812B component?  These are sold on the Adafruit site under the NeoPixel name.  For example I know of a few pattern examples like the Larson Scanner (Cylon), a candle light flicker or a rainbow pattern.  However I could not find a single pattern repository.

I am working on a [project](http://datadictionary.blogspot.com/2014/08/new-arduino-moving-rainbow-lab-for-kids.html) for kids learning to program the Arduino and it would be nice to have all the patterns in a single place and to be able to switch between the program examples with a mode switch.

If people send me links I am happy to post a blog of them.

Answer (score 7):

I have never found a single pattern repository, however FunkBoxing has a fantastic sketch with 30 or so patterns well documented. http://funkboxing.com/wordpress/?p=2154

He uses the Fast_SPI (now FastLED) library, which is truly exceptional!

https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/109127054924227823508

Answer (score 6):

Thake a look at [this library](http://yaab-arduino.blogspot.com/p/ala.html).

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2nSKQxpV_I) you can see some of the many animations available.

Comment: I like the names you have given each pattern - Sparkle, Bubble etc.